# Using iPod touch screen and digitizer with the Raspberry Pi

Tags: screen, touchscreen

I recently replaced the screen on my iPod touch 4th generation because the glass was cracked. I am now left with the old screen which is perfectly functional. I am wondering if there is any way I can utilize the LCD display and maybe even the touch digitizer with my Raspberry Pi. Is there are breakout connector for this screen that I can use to connect it to my Pi?

Comment: Short answer is No. The communication cahnnel between the screen and the host is not compatible with the Pi. You would need an intermediate PCB and Chip that are not cheap. Not sure about the digitizer. Sorry- I also thought about it a while back. I got about 5 old screens and digitziers.. useles...

Comment: @ppumkin Alright, thanks... What did you end up doing with them? Stuck 'em on a shelf?

Comment: Yup. In my electronics graveyard.. together with Romotive. The first discriminated robot in the world... (does not work in EU) It is an expensive shelf of crap... I wish I could just do something useful with it.

Comment: @ppumkin about the romotive: check http://pando.com/2012/10/16/why-romotive-returned-to-kickstarter-to-release-version-2-0-of-its-robot-for-everyone/

Comment: @ExploWare Yera great. I sent it to the guy in EU, it came back still broken. It sux and they annoyed me so badly. I will one day replace the PCB with Raspberry Pi instead. Atleast I got some nice wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence this can't be done.

"The communication channel between the screen and the host is not compatible with the Raspberry Pi." - ppumkin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! **But**, you need to buy/build:

- a breakout from iPod/iPhone connector to the converter
- a signal converter from native HSI (iPod/iPhone 4/5s) to HDMI (Rpi)

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCWGMM00ZEk) is a video of the [MIPI DSI Display Shield/HDMI Adapter](https://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter) project. I just found this, and its already an old project, so perhaps today there are simpler and cheaper solutions out there...

Then I found:

- Something about the [Ipod Video LCD hacking](http://www.electricstuff.co.uk/ipodlcd.html)
- And for the [iPod Nano 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TedIzmguP0)